# amazon s3 with AFAmazonS3Manager + AFNetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-s3, afnetworking-2

i'm trying to use AFAmazonS3Manager to upload some files to amazon s3, but i have 403 forbidden error, i try to list all objects in a bucket, same error.

the bucket is read/write for all.

code :

```
AFAmazonS3Manager *s3Mamanager=[[AFAmazonS3Manager alloc]initWithAccessKeyID:@"XXXXXX" secret:@"xxxxxx"];

[s3Mamanager getBucket:@"aBucket" success:^(id responseObject) {

} failure:^(NSError *error) {

}];
```

the error :

```
 Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed:
 forbidden (403)" UserInfo=0x170272580
 {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse:
 0x1782212e0> { URL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/aBucket } { status code:
 403, headers {
     "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
     Date = "Wed, 05 Mar 2014 21:01:55 GMT";
     Server = AmazonS3;
     "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
     "x-amz-id-2" = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
     "x-amz-request-id" = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; } }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403),
 NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/aBucket}
```

i use transmit (mac) and the samples of the Amazon s3 iOS API and it work fine, i want to use NSURLSession to upload files (with AFNetworking).

PS: in AFAmazonS3Manager, some competition block have'long long'  as parameters but AFNetwoking use NSIteger, so i modify them, i don't think that's the problem, but i'm really stack on this so ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is failing is because there is a bug on how the signature is being calculated in the AFAmazonS3RequestSerializer. It's trying to create the signature using:

```
NSString *canonicalizedResource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@%@", self.bucket, request.URL.path];
```

And at that point, self.bucket is null and request.URL.path contains the bucket. You can workaround that issue either by doing this:

```
AFAmazonS3Manager *s3Manager = [[AFAmazonS3Manager alloc]
                                initWithAccessKeyID:@"<accessKeyID>" secret:@"<secret>"];
[[s3Manager requestSerializer] setBucket:@"<YOUR BUCKET HERE>"];
[s3Manager getBucket:@"/" success:^(id responseObject) {}
             failure:^(NSError *error) {}];
```

or this:

```
AFAmazonS3Manager *s3Manager = [[AFAmazonS3Manager alloc]
                                initWithAccessKeyID:@"<accessKeyID>" secret:@"<secret>"];
[[s3Manager requestSerializer] setBucket:@"<YOUR BUCKET HERE>"];
[s3Manager enqueueS3RequestOperationWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/" parameters:nil
                                       success:^(id responseObject) {}
                                       failure:^(NSError *error) {}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using the putObjectWithFile method.

I was not setting a bucket but passing the bucket name on destinationPath which AFAmazonS3Manager appears to intend to support.  Either bucket property is set or pass it on path.

I submitted a pull request here with the fix that worked for me https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Client/pull/38

You are also correct on having to change long long to NSInteger.